# Stage failed errror when collecting results in Spark Deep Learning inference notebook in Windows

Tags: pyspark, deep-learning

I try several [Spark Deep Learning inference notebooks](https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-rapids-examples/tree/branch-23.06/examples/ML%2BDL-Examples/Spark-DL/dl_inference) on Windows. I run Spark in standalone mode with 1 worker with 12 cores (both driver-memory and executor-memory are set to 8G). I always get the same error when applying the deep learning model to the test dataset. For example, in the [MNIST image classification notebook](https://github.com/NVIDIA/spark-rapids-examples/blob/branch-23.06/examples/ML%2BDL-Examples/Spark-DL/dl_inference/tensorflow/image_classification.ipynb), when running this cell:

```
%%time
# first pass caches model/fn
preds = df.withColumn("preds", mnist(struct(df.columns))).collect()
```

I always get this error:

> Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o890.collectToPython. :
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
> Task 9 in stage 6.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 9.3
> in stage 6.0 (TID 69) (192.168.x.x executor 0):
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) at
> java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:105)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
> at
> org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at
> scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460) at
> scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93) at
> org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141) at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94) at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Driver stacktrace: at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
> at
> scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
> at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
> at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407) at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
> at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
> at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49) at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
> at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438) at
> org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2463) at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$collect$1(RDD.scala:1046) at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:407) at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:1045) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:448)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$collectToPython$1(Dataset.scala:4160)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4334)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4332)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
> at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4332) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:4157) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at
> sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at
> py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244) at
> py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374) at
> py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282) at
> py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79) at
> py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
> at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106) at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) at
> java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246) at
> java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265) at
> java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:387) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.PythonArrowOutput$$anon$1.read(PythonArrowOutput.scala:105)
> at
> org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner$ReaderIterator.hasNext(PythonRunner.scala:525)
> at
> org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
> at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:491) at
> scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460) at
> scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:460) at
> org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:388)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
> at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
> at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364) at
> org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328) at
> org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93) at
> org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
> at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141) at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
> at
> org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
> at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94) at
> org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> ... 1 more

I created and configured sparksession as below:

```
import findspark
findspark.init()
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName("spark-dl-inference") \
.master("spark://192.168.x.x:7077") \
.config("spark.executor.memory", "8g") \
.config("spark.driver.memory", "8g") \
.config("spark.python.worker.reuse",True) \
.getOrCreate()
```

This is the web ui of the master:
[image]

This is the web ui of the worker:
[image]

My window laptop has 24gb RAM. I've also reduced the model size (just 100k parameters) and the test dataset (only 70 images). I've tried increase the executor.memory to 12g but still got the same error.